# Why can I not store 16 bits in a logic in SystemVerilog?!

Tags: system-verilog

I am currently having issues when trying to store a 16bit number coming from the input of my module into one of my logic variables. When I set all the bits high in my test bench I get a value: 0000000000000001. Hope you can help! PS: Sorry, dont know how to insert code on here....

My code is shown below:

http://pastebin.com/cZCYKJqV

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is likely with this line:

```
regy = (!regy)+1;
```

`regy` is a 16-bit value.  Using the negation operator `(!)` on a multi-bit value is equivalent to `(value != 0)`.  So for any value of `regy` other than zero will set `regy` to 1.

If you are trying to invert all the bits and add 1, you need to use the `~` operator.

Example:

```
regy = (~regy)+1;
```

Comment: `~x + 1` is a twos complement inversion which could be written as `-x`